# D3.js stacked areas with color change above specific value

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

At work someone who isn't available anymore made an application with a `D3.js` graph in it, it wasn't finished yet and I have to finish it. However I wasn't and I still am not familiar with the D3.js library I could fix some things. But one thing I just can't fix, I have a graph with a colored area, that works and looks well, that has to show a red graph instead of yellow if a value is exceeded. In this case the value is -30, so above the red line (see pictures).

The image on the left shows what I have now and the right one what it needs to be:

[image: Current graph] [image: The solution]

I found out that multiple areas can be stacked with the [`d3.layout.stack()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout) function. But I only find examples with code using hard-coded `JSON` or multiple graphs at top of each other.
The code below is what I have now: (I cut out that is irrelevant)

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis") 
    .x(function (d) {return x(d.date); })
    .y0(function (d) {return y(0); })
    .y1(function (d) {return y(d.energy); });
var svg = d3.select("#datacontainer2").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
var context = svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate("+margin2.left+","+margin2.top + ")");

d3.csv("file:///data.txt", function (error, data) {
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.energy = d.energy; 
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function (d) { return d.date; })));
    y.domain([25, -50] /*d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.energy; }))*/ );
    x2.domain(x.domain());
    y2.domain(y.domain());

    focus.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .attr("d", area);

    // red line
    focus.append("svg:line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("x2", height * data.length)
        .attr("y1", (function (d) { return y(-30); } ))
        .attr("y2", (function (d) { return y(-30); }))
        .attr("stroke", "#ff0000")
        .attr("stroke-width", "3");
});
```

Also, all values below zero should be green colored, but this could be easily extended when having the code for above question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you might be looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/h45CD/.

```
Create a area gradient and color according to that.
// Set the threshold
    svg.append("linearGradient")                    
        .attr("id", "area-gradient")                // change from line to area
        .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")    
        .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(0))             
        .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(1000))          
    .selectAll("stop")                              
        .data([                                     
            {offset: "0%", color: "red"},           
            {offset: "30%", color: "red"},      
            {offset: "45%", color: "black"},        
            {offset: "55%", color: "black"},    
            {offset: "60%", color: "lawngreen"},    
            {offset: "100%", color: "lawngreen"}    
        ])                                          
    .enter().append("stop")                         
        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })       
        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

More on this you can find at [d3noob](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/applying-colour-gradient-to-graph-line.html).

Comment: This is made with a gradient and I don't want that.. Any idea how to edit this code so it's without the gradient?

Comment: Why wouldn't this work? You can set the offset range dynamically and assign colors. I updated the fiddle to show red and yellow only.http://jsfiddle.net/h45CD/3/. If you set your offset to something like this where suppose 50 is your threshold, then gradient will become like two colors.    
   {offset: "0%", color: "yellow"}, 
                        {offset: "49%", color: "yellow"}, 
   {offset: "50%", color: "red"}, 
   {offset: "100%", color: "red"},

Comment: I made it work with a question at http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/applying-colour-gradient-to-area-fill.html 
The only thing I need to know now is how to set the offset to a specific value, not percents

Comment: Why do you want to set direct values? Can't you get the percent value from absolute values? (Threshold value/max value) * 100 should give you the percent value. Right?

Comment: Yeah I know but then I'll get decimal digits

Comment: Use Math.Floor or ceil for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but in case it helps anyone who stumbles upon this question, I was having a similar problem. I hate the way gradients visually look, so I searched for an alternative answer. A different, and in my opinion a cleaner approach can be taken using this example from Mike himself.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062844

Comment: Yeah I found that code too but it didn't work with filled graphs.